# Create can0 interface for USB CAN Converter Basic (UCCB) on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, interface

I have a USB CAN Converter Basic as described here:
https://ucandevices.github.io/uccb.html

When I plug it into my Arch Linux laptop, `dmesg` shows the following:

```
usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5740, bcdDevice= 2.00
usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-6: Product: CAN_USB_ConverterBasic
usb 1-6: Manufacturer: CANDevices
usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 00000000001A
cdc_acm 1-6:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

`lsmod` shows the following entries:

```
slcan                  16384  0
can_dev                36864  0
can_raw                20480  0
can                    24576  1 can_raw
```

When I now try to activate the CAN interface with `sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000`, I get the error `Cannot find device "can0"`.

I think I have to add some `udev` rule or systemd thingy. But I cannot find the right start to do so.

**Update:**

I have now created a udev rule:

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/45-uccb.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5740", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", MODE="666", SYMLINK+="can0"
```

...but I can still not use the `ip link` command above.

Can anyone give me a hint on what's missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UCCB adapter introduces itself as a serial device (/dev/ttyACM0) so it has to be set up as slcan device.

```
slcan_attach -f -s5 -o /dev/ttyACM0
slcand ttyACM0 slcan0
```

With that, `ip link` can configure the device and `can0` can be used by `candump` and friends.